# JavaScript - Attaching event handlers to an element also attaches them to its children

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have this HTML. I want to attach mouseover and mouseleave events ONLY to the `.parent` element, but for some reason they also get attached to the children elements and I get weird behaviour.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Here's how I do it

```
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0]
parent.addEventListener('mouseover', eventHandler)
parent.addEventListener('mouseleave', eventHandler)
```

Whats going on and how to prevent it?

Comment: @misorude isnt event bubbling only upwards?

Comment: That combination of event handlers doesn’t make too much sense to begin with. The counterpart to mouseover would be mouseout, and the counterpart to mouseleave would be mouseenter. Make sure you know the difference in their behavior. You usually want to use the right combination, not mix them like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add event to child nodes and cancel the propagation of the event.

```js
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0]
parent.addEventListener('mouseover', eventHandler)
parent.addEventListener('mouseleave', eventHandler)

for (const child of parent.childNodes) {
  child.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
  child.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
}

function eventHandler() {
  console.log('hey');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: red; padding: 50px">
  <div class="child-1" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: blue"></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: green"></div>
</div>
```

Or you could do what everyone wants `pointer-event`

```js
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0]
parent.addEventListener('mouseover', eventHandler)
parent.addEventListener('mouseleave', eventHandler)

for (const child of parent.childNodes) {
  child.className += ' no-event'
}

function eventHandler() {
  console.log('hey');
}
```

```css
.no-event {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: red; padding: 50px">
  <div class="child-1" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: blue"></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't mix `mouseover` and `mouseleave`, they are not symmetrical

Comment: Your code works, but I just don't want the child nodes to have any such events, doesnt seem like a good solution

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer then do #2. add no-event class style to all child nodes

Answer (score 0):

It has to do how event catching and bubbling works. I copied the @ACD answer to see that it does behave differently. If you notice if we hover on child and move out to the parent the event is not called in this example. So child elements are no more the target of the event.

There are two phases of the event, Catching and Bubbling. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing). What is happening that event is triggered for the child and it is bubbling to the parent. You can check the event target via `event.target`

If we remove `pointer-events: none;` then the target is the child not the parent . and after the child handler is called the vent is propagated to the parent and then the parents callback is called.

```js
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0]
parent.addEventListener('mouseover', eventHandler)
parent.addEventListener('mouseleave', eventHandler)

 

function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.target, 'hey');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background: red; padding: 50px">
  <div class="child-1" style="pointer-events: none; width: 25px; height: 25px; background: blue"></div>
  <div class="child-2" style="pointer-events: none; width: 25px; height: 25px; background: green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: imagine you have thousands of child element with different classes and tag types. ain't that dirty?

Comment: It is just an example to show that it is more to event handling. Your solution is OK, but i just wanted to add more context, explain why. Besides a simple css selector can be written to add for all children, so to answer the question it will not get dirtier than stoping propagation for all children. (jus to iterate it to complement your response and not to dismiss it)

Answer (score -1):

Try `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseleave`. Don't mix them up. It's either the combination of `mouseover/mouseout` or `mouseenter/mouseleave`, because these combos are symmetrical.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter

```js
var logs = document.querySelector('.log');
var area = document.querySelector('.parent');

function eventHandler (e) {
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
    area.style.backgroundColor = '#c00';
  } else {
    area.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}

area.addEventListener('mouseenter', eventHandler);
area.addEventListener('mouseleave', eventHandler);
```

```css
.parent {
  background: #eee;
}
.child {
  padding: 30px 20px;
}
.child + .child {
  border-top: 1px dotted #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    foo bar baz
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    foo bar baz
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could fix this with css, by applying

```
.child-1, .child-2 {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

to the children, that way no interaction with the children is possible.

Alternatively, in the eventhandler you could check if the `event.target` is the parent or a childnode, hovering over a childnode will yield the childnode, hovering over `.parent` will yield the parent.